# ASP.NET. How to modify returned JSON (actionfilter)

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-filters

We have an ASP.NET application. We cannot edit source code of controllers. But we can implement ActionFilter.

One of our controller action methods returns JSON. Is it possible to modify it in ActionFilter? We need to add one more property to a returned object.

Maybe, some other way to achieve it?

Comment: I think in theory an `OnResultExecuted` should do what you want in an ActionFilter. It has access to the result via context.Result (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.resultexecutedcontext.result(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutedContext.Result) which should allow you to manipulate it as you want. It doesn't sound like a *nice* way of doing it but if you can't change the controller and presumably cannot change whatever factories are called by the controller then it sounds like your only option. I've not done it myself so can't say for sure that it will work...

Comment: How are you getting the JSON? Please show us the code so we can help.

Comment: Can you not just create a new action, which calls the old action then adds the field and passes on the new result?

Answer (score 12):

Found this interesting and as @Chris mentioned, though conceptually I knew this would work, I never tried this and hence thought of giving it a shot. I'm not sure whether this is an elegant/correct way of doing it, but this worked for me. (I'm trying to add `Age` property dynamically using `ActionResult`)

```
    [PropertyInjector("Age", 12)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(new { Name = "Hello World" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the filter:

```
public class PropertyInjector : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string key;
    object value;
    public PropertyInjector(string key, object value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var jsonData = ((JsonResult)filterContext.Result).Data;
        JObject data = JObject.FromObject(jsonData);
        data.Add(this.key,JToken.FromObject(this.value));

        filterContext.Result = new ContentResult { Content = data.ToString(), ContentType = "application/json" };

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

*Update*

If it's not dynamic data which is to be injected, then remove filter constructor and hard code key & value directly and then the filter could be registered globally without editing the controller
`GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new PropertyInjector());`

Comment: Surely this does require editing the controller in order to add the attribute?

Comment: @Milney if it's not dynamic data which is to be injected, then the filter could be registered globally without touching controller

Comment: @Milney register filter globally, have it inspect request to make sure it is the desired controller action and perform desired change if it is.